# How to route Vdd and Vss to CD4011 in Pcbnew

Tags: kicad

As first-time KiCAD user, I was able to draw a simple schema with a CD4011 driving 2 relais. The "electrical rules checker" -finally- gives no errors or warnings. After creating the netlist and placing the components on the PCB, there is no way to route a track from the Vdd power-in pin to pin 14 or from the Vss power-in pin to pin 7 of the CD4011. Worse, I can place a track between Pins 7 and 14 . . .

In the standard symbol_dir, pins 7 and 14 are declared as VSS and VDD "power input" :

[image: CD4011_symbol_dir]

This is (part) of the schema with "show invisible pins" activated :

[image: Eeschema_CD4011]

No hidden pins at the CD4011 ...

After reading lots of info on various websites, I tried this power-schema :

[image: Eeschema_Power_part]

In Pcbnew highlighting the "GND" net does not include any pin of the CD4011  ...

[image: Pcbnew_highlight_GND_net]

Even more curious, Pcbnew lets me connect pins 7 and 14 of the CD4011 :

[image: Pcbnew_CD4011_tack_pins_7_14]

Where oh where did I go wrong ? ? ?

Comment: Did you connect the pins in eeschema? As they are not invisible you need to do this. For that you might need to add the 5th unit (unit E)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing "Unit E" of the quad pack.  How this symbol works is there is a part of each of the quad (Unit A -> Unit D) and then an additional one for the power.

Your first image shows it but then the next images does not.

[image]
[image]

So your circuit should have 5 components. So a quick throwaway design:

[image]

Finally the layout with a quick ground trace to see all GND pins highlighted

[image]

In short, ensure all parts of a multi-symbol part are placed and wired